# TFS not resolving AspNet Nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I'm using the online TFS at visualstudio.com. My solution builds with no issues on my local computer.

The build is set to restore the nuget packages. It restores all of the needed packages except the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` packages for some reason.

Other packages are ok, for instance:

```
2018-02-11T05:35:17.0087836Z Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.
```

TFS executes the following commands to restore the nuget packages:

```
2018-02-11T05:34:13.9983013Z Saving NuGet.config to a temporary config file.
2018-02-11T05:34:14.0034492Z [command]D:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.3.0\x64\nuget.exe sources Add -NonInteractive -Name NuGetOrg -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -ConfigFile D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_23.config
2018-02-11T05:34:19.0878753Z Package Source with Name: NuGetOrg added successfully.
2018-02-11T05:34:19.0887956Z Saving NuGet.config to a temporary config file.
2018-02-11T05:34:19.0987326Z [command]D:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.3.0\x64\nuget.exe restore D:\a\1\s\BFT\BFT\BFT.sln -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive -ConfigFile D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_23.config
2018-02-11T05:35:17.0078970Z NuGet Version: 4.3.0.4406
2018-02-11T05:35:17.0079582Z MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.5.180.51428' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
```

The log gives the following error when reaching the mvc related binaries:

```
Primary reference "System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
2018-02-11T05:36:10.4565719Z ##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2041,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

The project's `packages.config` contains the reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Please let me know what other information is needed help resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you have `System.Web.Helpers` directly referenced in your project? If not you might be able to get it working by adding it as assembly reference with copy local true

Comment: @ThePretendProgrammer Thanks for the idea. It is referenced, and also it set to copy local true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the references that TFS was not able to resolve were linked to the respective package folders being checked into source control. The folders that were not checked in were resolved correctly, the folders that were did not resolve.

The solution was to remove all folders under `/packages/` from source control, then TFS successfully resolved the references.

Comment: How did you delete the packages folder from the source control? in my source there is no packages folders and I'am having the same issue with Newtonsoft.json nuget